# Which color set use for interactive color choice on web page?

Tags: web-applications, user-interface, colors, color-picker

This is generic UI question.

In my web application user can select color of some parts of application. User wants to change each color separately so I don't use tuned color themes. Color must be easily transfered by clipboard, so I prefer text input rather then mouse clicking in color wheel or so. Text input has ajax-based popup for offering some predefined colors.

There are so many color sets which can be used for predefined colors in application:

- 16 old-fashioned basic HTML web colors (aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, gray...)
- extended [CSS web colors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colornames.asp) (aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure, beige...)
- [X11 color names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) (basicaly same as CSS colors with some clashes)
- web safe colors (eye-tuned colors without names)

Which color set is better to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, wrong question, my fault.

For those who interested: finally I have chosen list of extended CSS colors, sorted by "shade" (not by name) just like [here](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/namedcol.htm).